Flat a python dict containing lists
I am trying to normalize a dictionary containing some lists. As an MVCE (Minimal, Verifiable, Complete Example), consider the following dictionary:
test_dict = {
    'name' : 'john',
    'age' : 20,
    'addresses' : [
        {
            'street': 'XXX',
            'number': 123,
            'complement' : [
                'HOUSE',
                'NEAR MARKET'
            ]
        },
        {
            'street': 'YYY',
            'number': 456,
            'complement' : [
                'AP',
                'NEAR PARK'
            ]
        },
    ],
    'phones' : [
        '123456'
    ],
    'gender' : 'MASC'
}

I want each list found in the dictionary to generate a line, so my desired output is:
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'HOUSE', 'phones': '123456', 'gender' : 'MASC'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'NEAR MARKET', 'phones': '123456', 'gender' : 'MASC'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'AP', 'phones': '123456', 'gender' : 'MASC'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'NEAR PARK', 'phones': '123456', 'gender' : 'MASC'}

However, when I run my code, I am not able to iterate over more than one list. My intention was to develop a recursive function, so I wouldn't have to worry about a dictionary with more complex structures (a dictionary with more lists inside dictionaries, etc.). However, when I run my code, the output I get is:
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'HOUSE'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'NEAR MARKET'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'AP'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'NEAR PARK'}
{'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'phones': '123456'}

My python code (MVCE):
def get_list_values(lista, dicionario, key_name, results):
    if len(lista) > 0:
        for l in lista:
            if isinstance(l, dict):
                search_values(l, dicionario.copy(), results)
            else:
                dicionario_metodo = dicionario.copy()
                dicionario_metodo[key_name] = l
                results.append(dicionario_metodo)

def search_values(dicionario, test, results):
    for k, v in dicionario.items():
        if isinstance(v, list):
            get_list_values(v, test, k, results )
        else: 
            test[k] = v
    if not any(isinstance(v, list) for v in dicionario.values()):
        results.append(test.copy())
    return results 


test = {}
results = []
for r in search_values(test_dict, test, results):
    print(r)

In which part of my recursion am I going wrong, so it doesn't generate my desired output?

Edit 1:
test_dict = {
    'name' : 'john',
    'age' : 20,
    'addresses' : [
        {
            'street': 'XXX',
            'number': 123,
            'complement' : [
                'HOUSE',
                'NEAR MARKET'
            ]
        },
        {
            'street': 'YYY',
            'number': 456,
            'complement' : [
                'AP',
                'NEAR PARK'
            ]
        },
    ],
    'type' : {
        'category': 'G123',
        'products': [
            'test1',
            'test2'
        ]
    },
    'phones' : [
        '123456'
    ],
    'gender' : 'MASC'
}


Does this answer your question? python flatten dict with leaving the same key name after flatten

No, this answer doesn't turn list values into single values. This flattend the list to list.

I vaguely recall there being a fairly concise way to do this using the jq bindings.

Where/how does your code try to generate all combinations of, in this example, a phone with an address?

@CooperativistKid, just to be clear, in your last data input, as you have 2 different products, your output will double, with one set of everything else for each product, right? Check the output with my answer below for reference.

It took me some time to get this right, but check this out.
def flat(out, *kvs):
    match kvs:
        case []: yield out
        case (k, []), *kvs: yield from flat(out, *kvs)
        case (k, list(l)), *kvs: 
            for v in l: yield from flat(out, (k, v), *kvs)
        case (_, dict(d)), *kvs: yield from flat(out, *d.items(), *kvs)
        case (k, v), *kvs: yield from flat([*out, (k, v)], *kvs)
        case _: raise ValueError("Invalid")

That is all you need! This implementation makes extensive use of recursion, pattern mathcing and generators.
You can try it out like this:
x = map(dict, flat([], (..., test_dict)))
print(*x, sep='\n')

# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'HOUSE', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'NEAR MARKET', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'AP', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'NEAR PARK', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}

With your second input data, result would be as below:
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'HOUSE', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test1', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'HOUSE', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test2', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'NEAR MARKET', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test1', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'XXX', 'number': 123, 'complement': 'NEAR MARKET', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test2', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'AP', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test1', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'AP', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test2', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'NEAR PARK', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test1', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}
# {'name': 'john', 'age': 20, 'street': 'YYY', 'number': 456, 'complement': 'NEAR PARK', 'category': 'G123', 'products': 'test2', 'phones': '123456', 'gender': 'MASC'}

Edit: Mapped the key-value pairs into dicts as per requirements, made the code neatier.

This is pretty.

I was looking forward to try out python pattern matching, and it is a blast!


In which part of my recursion am I going wrong, so it doesn't generate my desired output?

One could say it goes wrong where it appends a result before all keys are known without ever fixing this result. However, I don't see a way of correcting this without substantial changes to the given code.
def get_list_values(lista, key_name):
    results = []
    for l in lista:
        if isinstance(l, dict):
            results += search_values(l)
        else:
            results += [{key_name: l}]
    return results

def search_values(dicionario):
    results = [{}]
    for k, v in dicionario.items():
      results_metodo = []
      for r in results: # multiply current results by new values
        if isinstance(v, list):
            for d in get_list_values(v, k): results_metodo += [dict(r, **d)]
        elif isinstance(v, dict):
            for d in search_values(v): results_metodo += [dict(r, **d)]
        else:
            results_metodo += [dict(r, **{k: v})]
      results = results_metodo
    return results 

for r in search_values(test_dict): print(r)


Hey, @Armali! Thanks for your answer. For that dict type it worked perfectly, but if you add the key of edit 1 on the first dict first level it will not work, since products key is in the second level.

Okay, I added code lines for the new case of a dictionary directly contained in a dictionary.
